# How to link to a custom .php page in my folder

Tags: php, pages

I have created a custom page that I have called mypage.php.

It is in my template folder with al the other pages (index.php, page.php, ...)

I want this page to be opened when i click on the below code.

```
<a href="<?php site_url(); ?>/mypage.php">Go to page</a>
```

When I click on the link the url in my browser look like: http://localhost:8888/mypage.php which I guess is correct.

BUT it uses index.php as template ignoring the code I have into mypage.php

So all i am getting at the moment is an empty page with only my header and footer.

Is it possible to use pages in this way with Wordpress? I had a look online and on this site but I haven't been able to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of that page? I mean why just don't create a page within WordPress?

Comment: @Laxmana Because i have some custom code in there to create a PDF from html. I am passing an ID via the url, then I use the ID to find the page i want to convert and I use some code to convert the html into PDF. Please let me know if i havent been too clear!

Comment: You can do it through [WordPress custom template pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) or [WordPress endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress doesn't load templates that way.

## First: give the template a name:

To load a page template, first you'll have to make sure your template has a name. To do that, you'll have to have the following CODE in your template file (here `mypage.php`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Page
 */
```

Once you have the above PHP comment, WordPress will recognise it as a template file.

## Then, assign the template to a page:

Now you'll have to create a WordPress `page` (from `wp-admin`).

While you create the `page`, WordPress will give you the option to choose a custom template (if there is one). After you choose the template and `Publish`, that page will use your `mypage.php` file as a template.

[image: Add Page Template]

Comment: Thank you. this is perfect! I still need to create the page from wp-admin in order to get a custom template to work! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

@Martina Sartor, you can use wordpress custom template process. Add a the below comment to the file you wish to make your custom page. Then go to the admin area and create a page, and select your custom template for that page.

Please review

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Full-width layout
Template Post Type: post, page, event
*/
// Page code here...
```

mention your template name here

You can also review wordpress documentation for same.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Thank you, I did try this and I have tried it again just now but it is not working. The link keeps going directing me to index.php

Comment: I have provided same solution to you but it did not work for you .when some else provided , it worked for you.. great..!!

Comment: @shishirmishra I feel for you, happened to me too :) But I guess the accepted answer explained better + the screen shot helped perhaps. Anyways, +1 from me for future motivation :)

Comment: @scott, I have also mentioned  url for more detailed information.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking to do is inserting custom php files inside your theme but sadly WP will not let you use .php files easily but fortunately it provides an alternate and more efficient way for including .php files.

WordPress provides `get_template_part` function & `custom page templates`. you can use these methods instead.

above answer has explained page templates and in addition to that you can use your custom php files included into that template or anywhere else using `get_template_part` function. this works same as `require` or `include` native php functions.

**template**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Page template
 */
```

php file to be included for example is `some-file.php` inside root folder. then you would write

```
get_template_part( 'some', 'file' );
```